# What to try after restarting my Azure Web App to resolve "Service Unavailable"?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

my *Azure web app on Linux* is giving me **"Service Unavailable"** all of a sudden. It has been pulling a private image from Docker Hub well for months. Now, as I said, I am getting **Service Unavailable** and the LogFiles under Kudu seem to say that it is having trouble pulling the image.  I can pull it successfully on my laptop. I have restarted (and stopped/started) the app several times but still no go.  Any ideas of something else to try?

**Extra Info**

My LogFiles folder contains a docker log which says "docker pull returned STDERR>> Error response from daemon: repository myname/my-repo not found: does not exist or no pull access" but, I am able to pull this private container on my laptop and I double checked the credentials in the docker blade. Plus, I have made no changes since this worked a few days ago.

Comment: You sure need to provide more details, including logfiles/error messages. If the system tells you it is unable to get some resource, you should investigate that to start. If you have a network problem that blocks access to docker hub for example restarting your app several times will not fix anything.

Comment: I have added some clarification of the pull problem.  Just assuming this is the root cause of my 503. Thanks for the attention!